# Focus in parent even if click on child element

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a UserControl (let's call it "`PresentationCell`")  which contains a label, and an PictureBox.
In another control, which is using this `PresentationCell`, I have added an event

```
presentationCell.GotFocus += OnFocus;

private void OnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is PresentationCell current)
        current.BackColor = Color.Azure;
}
```

This will not be fired, if I click / focus on the Label or `PictureBox` that is within the `PresentationCell`.

How can I make it fire, when just something within the `PresentationCell` is in focus?

Comment: Because there are no routed events in winforms, [Control.ContainsFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.containsfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) and polling might do. Other possibility is to route events yourself, e.g. every control have to propagate event up or you have to monitor for children and subscribe to their events.

Comment: Have you read https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/43c6a576-3aef-4ef2-9a0f-e00dee5f0894/how-do-you-disable-focus-of-a-control?forum=winforms ?

Comment: As an option, Instead of using Label and PictureBox, draw the text and image yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Reza. Did not think of that. Helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that the Label and PictureBox controls aren't selectable controls, so they aren't able to receive focus from mouse clicks.

What you could to instead, is to handle the mouse click event and check if you have hit the PresentationCell. If the PresentationCell is hit you can programatically set the focus like so:

hitPresentationCell.Focus();

This will then fire the GotFocus event.

In your OnFocus method you will have to switch the focus to another control or the event will fire endlessly.